# Julia's behaviour for atexit in module

Tags: julia, atexit

Assume I have a module `SomeModule.jl`:

```
module SomeModule

export use_me

function use_me()
  println("I'm useful!")
end

function call_me_in_the_end()
  println("This is the end")
end

atexit(call_me_in_the_end)

end
```

And `main.jl` using this module:

```
import SomeModule: use_me

use_me()
```

Since function passed into `atexit` [is called at process exit](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.atexit) I expect to see when calling `main.jl`:

```
I'm useful!
This is the end
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
This is the end
I'm useful!
```

on the first call, and only:

```
I'm useful!
```

for all subsequent calls, until I make changes in `SomeModule.jl`. After changes are made everything repeats.

I've tried to bring `atexit` outside of the module, like so:

```
module SomeModule
  ...
end

import SomeModule: call_me_in_the_end

atexit(call_me_in_the_end)
```

but result is the same.

So, two questions:

1. Why `call_me_in_the_end` is called only once and how to fix it?
2. How to make `call_me_in_the_end` be called in the end?

Julia's version is 1.7.3 for macOS x86

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module gets compiled after the first run and hence  the exit hook does not get attached in subsequent runs.

Instead you should have used the special `__init__` that gets executed whenever module gets loaded:

```
module SomeModule

function __init__()
  #this gets executed whenever using SomeModule is called regardless of precompilation
  println("Attaching the hook")
  atexit(call_me_in_the_end)
end

function call_me_in_the_end()
  println("This is the end")
end

end
```

Regarding the output order this is just related to stream buffering and such behavior is observed quite often in multitask application.
Simply add `flush(stdout)` after your last `println` statement in your code before `exit()` is called and you will be good.